# Return non-distinct object based on three different fields

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Given the following, I would like to be able to pull out the non-distinct values based on two fields: Name and Country.  In this example, I want return the first two in the list.

```
List<City> cities = new List<City>
{
new City{ Name = "Sydney", Country = "Australia", Galaxy = "Mine"  },
new City{ Name = "Sydney", Country = "Australia", Galaxy = "Yours" },
new City{ Name = "New York", Country = "USA", Galaxy = "Ours"},
new City{ Name = "Paris", Country = "France", Galaxy = "Theirs" },

};
```

Comment: Specify exactly what do you want? Do you want distinct values of Name and Country fields? Why then _first two in the list_? If you want first two - by what mean to select them? The question is quite ambiguous

Comment: good point, my mistake for not being more clear.  The intended result would yield the first two in the list.  lazyberezovsky gave the the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query will return non-distinct cities by name and country (i.e. first two in your case):

```
IEnumerable<City> query = 
    cities.GroupBy(c => new { c.Name, c.Country })
          .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
          .SelectMany(g => g);
```